# The tonal function of a bar in minuet by krieger

Tags: theory

This is Minuet by J.Krieger 
[image]

If I look at the 6-7-8 bars, there is the following chord progression:
E - E(7) - Am

With a trill in the 7th bar. I feel like the 6 bar does a kind of "teasing" in a tonal sense i.e from the dominant E you want to go straight to the tonic but the trill in the 7th prolongs the tension.

Is my analysis correct? and is there a name for this "structure"?

Comment: The tonic is A.

Comment: You are correct as to the chords inferred, assuming you want to count the last beat of the sixth measure and the first beat of the second measure merely as passing tones, but I regret that I don't know of a name for the prolonged dominant seventh trill here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analysis is correct.  This piece is in A minor.  The chord progression that you've spelled out (E-E7-Am or V-V7-I) is called a cadence.  If you wanted to put a name on the structure you've noted it would be a cadential extension.  Usually this term is applied to a longer delay in the return to the tonic (Am) chord but any place where the Dominant (V or E in this key) function chord is continued past the expected point of resolution could be considered a cadential extension.

You can find some more in depth information about the larger musical theoretical structures in Common Practice music in the book "A Practical Approach to Form in Music" by Peter Spencer.